# What is image masking?

Tags: python, image, masking

I have been learning image processing in python for the past few weeks. That was when I stumbled upon this term called **Image Masking**. I referred to lots of websites, but still couldn't find a proper explanation for it. Could you please explain what image masking is with an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Image masking.](https://www.quora.com/What-is-image-masking-1)
There are literally lot of answers. Here's a small portion.

```
Masking Image

is a process of graphics software like Photoshop to hide some portions of an image and to reveal some portions. It is a non-destructive process of image editing. Most of the time it enables you to adjust and tweak the mask later if necessary. Very often, it is efficient and more creative way of the image manipulation services.
```

It is used for changing background which are blurry or not good-looking